# \noindent inside a command not working

Tags: macros, indentation, description

i looked a lot for a solution to my problem but i don´t seem to be able to find one. Here is the summary:

in my document I have a custom command for a description and i would like this description to NOT have an indentation.

The document is

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}


\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\color{royalblue}\itshape\small#1}}
\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{11/2017x-x09/2018} 

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\parbox[t]{\datebox}{\small #1} {\small \textbf{#2}}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\small {#1}\noindent\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\NewEntry{10/2018-Present}{Corrector of Discrete Mathematics, \textsc{University Ulm}}
\Description{\MarginText{ SK Mathematik} Algebraic structures, Elementary Number Theory, Finite bodies, Foundations of Coding Theory.  \ \ $\cdotp$\ \ }

\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of this space between "Algebraic" and "Foundation"?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think the problem is the space right after `{ SK Mathematik }`, not the paragraph indentation. Removing it should fix the problem. If not, please add a [minimal but complete document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question that replicates the output

Comment: Sadly it did not solve it. I updated the extract with more Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your code: it was due to the space you left between `\margintext{...}` and `Algebraic:

```
\documentclass[twoside, svgnames]{article}%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\small#1\noindent\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\color{RoyalBlue}\itshape\small#1}}

\begin{document}

\Description{\MarginText{ SK Mathematik }%
Algebraic structures, Elementary Number Theory, Finite bodies, Foundations of Coding Theory.}

Some more text

Some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Another pair of eyes telling me a very basic oversight was exactly what i needed.

Comment: The `%` is only needed because of the mis-use of `\noindent` in the definition prematurely starting the paragraph, so space is not ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The `\noindent` in `\Descritiption` forces the paragraph to start too early so the space after the `\marginpar` is set in hmode so visible rather than being ignored.

You can delete them, but unfortunately a `\marginpar` in vertical mode comes on the line *above* the paragraph, so it is simplest to use `\noindent` before the `\marginpar`, and then `\ignorespaces` to ignore any spaces following.

re-using Bernard's example as the one in the question produces no output.

```
\documentclass[twoside, svgnames]{article}%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \raggedright\small#1\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\small\noindent\marginpar{\color{RoyalBlue}\itshape#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\Description{\MarginText{ SK Mathematik }
Algebraic structures, Elementary Number Theory, Finite bodies, Foundations of Coding Theory.}

Some more text

Some more text

\end{document}
```